# Update browser automatically with cshtml file changes without doing a browser refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

When editing a cshtml file I want my browser to automatically update after making changes to it but doing so without doing a browser refresh.

I 'think' I remember reading that this is possible in Visual Studio 2013 with the new Web Essentials and browser link capabilities.  Is this possible, if so how do I enable it?